# DRF: "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a `register` and `sign in` API(TokenAuthentication) using DRF.

This is my views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from .serializers import AccountSerializer
from .models import Account

class AuthRegister(APIView):
    """
    Register a new user.
    """
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        allquery = Account.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(allquery, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class AuthLogin(APIView):
    ''' Manual implementation of login method '''

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        allquery = Account.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(allquery, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        # Generate token and add it to the response object
        if account is not None:
            login(request, account)
            return Response({
                'status': 'Successful',
                'message': 'You have successfully been logged into your account.'
            }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response({
            'status': 'Unauthorized',
            'message': 'Username/password combination invalid.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import AuthRegister
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
    url(r'^register/$', AuthRegister.as_view()),
]
```

When I run the server i get the following error.

[image]

After filing the details the user gets added to the database but when I tr to log in error occurs.

`"Unable to log in with provided credentials."`

Not able to figure out the error. Please anyone help!

Answer (score 1):

You've not implemented a `get` method in your `AuthRegister` view. DRF does not know how to *respond* to GET requests for that view, so it assumes you do not want to allow such category of requests.

You should implement a `get` method that implements what action to be taken (your server response) for GET requests.

Comment: What should I return in `get()`?

Comment: Data from your serializer etc. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views

Comment: What about the `AuthLogin`, I implemented the same `get()` in it it would give the error

Comment: @YatharthaJoshi I don't see any `def get(...)` in `AuthLogin` either.

Comment: I have made changes locally, I will make here too

Comment: I have added the `get()`

Comment: After logged in successfully I want a token to be generated. That is not happening here. And I m not able to figure out the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154976/discussion-between-yathartha-joshi-and-moses-koledoye).